# Reproducir video en MediaElement WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de escritorio WPF, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015.

En el cual al momento de ir a la ubicación del video se reproduzca, tengo el siguiente código.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ReconocimientoVoz.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReconocimientoVoz"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="28*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="19*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectColor" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="55,46,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblColor" Content="lblColor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnEscuchar" Content="Escuchar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Click="btnEscuchar_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Color:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlayer" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="161" 
                  Margin="0,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" LoadedBehavior="Play"/>

</Grid>
```

En Mediaelement configure LoadedBehavior en Play para que supuestamente al momento de darle la ruta del video se pueda visualizar en el control.

C#

```
private void btnEscuchar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblColor.Content = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            escucha.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            escucha.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
            //escucha.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(lector);
            escucha.SpeechRecognized += Escucha_SpeechRecognized;
            escucha.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            escucha.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Aviso");
        }
    }

    private void Escucha_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var palabra in e.Result.Words)
        {
            lblColor.Content = palabra.Text;
            if (palabra.Text == "rojo")
            {
                rectColor.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            else if (palabra.Text == "azul")
            {
                rectColor.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            }
            else if (palabra.Text == "amarillo")
            {
                rectColor.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                mediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(@"D:\PruebasCSharp\ReconocimientoVoz\Video\hola.wmv");                  
            }

            else if (palabra.Text == "hola")
            {
                mediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(@"D:\PruebasCSharp\ReconocimientoVoz\Video\hola.wmv");
                //mediaPlayer.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

Cuando se cumple la condición llama a la ruta del video pero no se reproduce nada en el control MediaElement.

¿No se que puede estar pasando, no reproduce nada?, ¿necesito alguna configuración extra al control o al formulario? espero me puedan ayudar de antemano gracias.

NOTA: He realizado pruebas simples en la cual solo se programa en el XAML y no he podido reproducir nada, es por eso que creo que debe faltar alguna configuración tanto en el control o en la ventana(formulario). Solo logro escuchar el audio del video pero no muestra las imágenes.

Comment: Ya probaste poner mediaPlayer.play() despues de asignar el Source? o igual podrias ponerle el atributo AutoPlay en true

Comment: No, por lo que intento es hacerlo cuando le doy la ruta al objeto.

Comment: @yms He comprobado que si lo reproduce porque se escucha el audio de un video que descargue pero no se ve la imagen del video, estoy usando Windows 10 64 bits y Visual Studio 2015, ¿no se que es lo que evita no ver el video?

Comment: Hola, prueba a manejar el evento `MediaElement.MediaFailed` para poder al menos mostrar un mensaje de error.

Comment: También ten cuenta que algunos códecs funcionan en x64 y otros en x86.

Comment: Lo que dice @SergioParraGuerra, si se oye y no se ve, probablemente tu video necesita un codec especial. Te funciona bien en el media player de Windows normal en la misma PC?

Comment: @yms si se oye bien el problema es que no se visualiza el video, es mas descargue una app de Microsoft y no se ve el video solo se oye. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-Use-Media-Element-b8ce7e92

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra  Hice lo que me recomendaste y efectivamente cuando lanzo la aplicación me manda el siguiente error excepcion de hresult 0xc00d11b1 el cual indica en el foro de Microsoft que tiene que ver con los códec halle una respuesta el cual tiene un link roto. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2d80888f-4f1d-450c-90ee-2568b7283e23/mediaelement-failing-with-exception-from-hresult-0xc00d11b1?forum=wpf

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra Logre solucionarlo con VLC.Dotnet, gracias!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He tenido demasiado problemas con el control MediaElement y he logrado solucionarlo con Vlc.Dotnet que me recomendó [Sergio Parra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/1898).

La implementación es la siguiente:

- Primero hay que agregar como referencia al proyecto WindowsFormsIntegration
- Luego agregar namespace al XAML y agregar el control.

  ```
  <Window x:Class="ReconocimientoVoz.WindowVLC"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      **xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf"**
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReconocimientoVoz"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Title="WindowVLC" Height="300" Width="300">

  <Grid >
      <vlc:VlcControl x:Name="vlcPlayer" />
  </Grid>
  ```
- Agregar el siguiente código al archivo .cs

  ```
  public partial class WindowVLC : Window
  {
      public WindowVLC()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectory =
              //replace this path with an appropriate one
              new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\");
          vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.EndInit();
          vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri(@"D:\PruebasCSharp\ReconocimientoVoz\Video\hola.wmv"));
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Gracias por darle formato @Flxtr

Comment: A la orden maestro ;)

Answer (score 1):

El componente MediaElement utiliza el mecanismo de codecs de Windows (leer sobre DirectShow y Windows Media Foundation para más detalles de cómo funciona internamente). Básicamente cada video tiene un formato de "contenedor" (mkv, avi, etc) que dice como se almacena cada parte (stream) del video. El video contiene varios streams (video, audio, subtitulo), y cada uno viene codificado con cierto formato (mpeg, divx, h264, mp3, aac, etc) que es independiente del formato contenedor general. A los componentes de Windows que permiten procesar todos estos formatos se les llama comúnmente "codec" (codificador/decodificador o compresor/decompresor)

Windows viene por defecto con soporte para muchos formatos contenedores y de audio/video, pero hay formatos que no son soportados por defecto y necesitan instalación de software adicional.

Para tu caso particular, prueba el video que estás tratando de reproducir con un player "auto-contenido" gratuito, [videolan player](https://www.videolan.org/index.html) por ejemplo, que no utilizan los codecs de Windows, y si funciona, es que tu video necesita un codec (decodificador) especial que no viene instalado por defecto.

Para diagnosticar mejor el problema de tu aplicación, pruébala con un video que sepas de antemano que funciona bien en tu sistema, usando por ejemplo el Windows Media Player que viene por defecto.

Comment: Hice la prueba que me indico Sergio y efectivamente al ejecutar la aplicación me lanza un error el cual menciono en los comentarios de la pregunta, el  cual habla de códec y por mala suerte el link de una respuesta esta roto, por otro lado hice lo que me indicaste he probado un video con extensión wmv en el reproductor de Windows media y en VLC que descargue de la pagina que me recomendaste y en ambos reproductores funciona de maravilla.

Comment: Siendo el caso que necesite instalación de alguna librería en mi proyecto ¿Cuál sería, no se que códec con exactitud estoy necesitando? ¿O quizás debería de probar usar otro control que haga lo mismo?

Comment: Existe un wrapper de librerías de VLC. https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet

Comment: Y también puedas echar un vistazo a https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/MicrosoftHLSSDK?files=1

Comment: @yms Me interesa funcione de tal manera que el control MediaElement pueda reproducir el video y audio.

Comment: @yms solo me interesa que funcione cualquiera del primer formato que me funcione sea wmv, avi. cualquiera de ellos.

Comment: A ver si entendí, el wmv funciona en media player pero no en tu aplicación? Si es el caso el problema entonces no es necesariamente codecs. De hecho wmv es un formato de microsoft, deberia funcionar siempre.